# How can I paste to next line and enter insert mode on current line?

Tags: vim

I'm brand new to vim. A common pattern I am dealing with looks like this

```
myFunction :: some code
myFunction = some more code
```

how could I create a command where after executing I look like this

```
myFunction
myFunction
```

and am in insert mode with my cursor on the end of the first 'myFunction' ?

Comment: By "command" do you mean you're looking for a Vimscript function? Or do you want any general technique to make this workflow faster?

Comment: to achieve your text transformation is easy, however, I don't see why you want to "paste" to next, you just want to keep `myFunction`s in the two lines, and cut the rest part after them, don't u? pls clarify your question/problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are copying the first line to the down then maybe try `yy` for yanking the whole (first) line, `P` for pasting the line before the cursor and `A` to go in insert mode at the end of first line.

And you can use `:map` to do whole thing at one. Like `:map 'l yyPA`

Answer (score 1):

I have found an almost perfect solution "using ultisnips plugin", the only thing missing is the cursor position. I am considering an already typed text:

You must select the target lines (use vip in normal mode) and use your defined trigger on ultisnips

```
snippet trigger "Description" w
`!p
import re
snip.rv = re.sub("(^\w+).*", r"\1", snip.v.text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
`
endsnippet
```